# Change Woocommerce Booking Label

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to change the woocommerce booking duration field's label which currently simply reads "Duration".

It doesnt seem possible through the admin area, or i cannot find it. Is is possible to change it via functions.php does anyone know?

This is the code for the label on the product page:

```
<label for="wc_bookings_field_duration">Duration:</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
add_filter( 'booking_form_fields', 'custom_booking_form_fields' );

function custom_booking_form_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['wc_bookings_field_duration']['label'] = "The new Label";
    return $fields;
}
```